# Problem accessing unknown SMB server via pysm while the server is up and running

Tags: python, error-handling, smb

I am trying to get all shared devices of unknown SMB servers. 
While trying to connect via SMBConnection.connect() function it refuses to connect to the server and connection get lost or no connection at all. Meanwhile I get exceptions in Python I can connect to that server from my Desktop environment.
What could cause this. I have a list of SMB servers varying from Linux to Windows hosts.

```
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection 
import socket
ips ['x.x.x.x','x.x.x.x'...]
for ip in ips :
    print(ip)
    try:
        hostname = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
    except socket.herror as e :
        print("[-][-][-]Uknknown host")
        continue
    smb_conn = SMBConnection(username='Guest',password="",my_name='name',remote_name=hostname)
    try:
        is_connected = smb_conn.connect(ip,timeout=60)
    except :
        print("[!] %s is up but refuses smb connection:(( "%ip)
        #print("Na not responding shit")
        continue
    if is_connected:
        print("[+] %s connected"%ip)
        try:
            shares = smb_conn.listShares()
            for share in shares :
                print(share.name)
            print("\n\n\n")
        except smb.smb_structs.OperationFailure as e:
            print (e.message)
    break
```

UPDATE: 
While executing this script I get TimeoutError while the server is up and running and accessible through Desktop SMB connection.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
In some cases the SMB server is listening or port 445 and not the NetBIOS port 139. By default the connect() function tries to connect to port 139 but it can be modified by connect(ip,port,timeout) parameters.